# Given a string (text) T in length n, need to find if there is two string (non-empty) A and B so T=AAAB.

Tags: algorithms

Given a string (text) T in length n, need to find if there is two string (non-empty) A and B so T=AAAB.
I'm trying to develop an algorithm using the KMP algorithm but I still can't find the right way to use it so I can solve this in the best time complexity. I need help in determining if it is possible to solve the problem using KMP or if there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let our string be $S$. Note that if we can in constant time if $S[:i] = S[i:2\cdot i] = S[2\cdot i:3\cdot i]$, then we can solve your problem in linear time by checking all $i$ s.t. $3 \cdot i < |S|$.

To check $i$, we can either use [Z-function](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html) or [Rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash). KMP is usually implemented using [Prefix function](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/prefix-function.html), which is quite similar to Z-function, but less applicable for your problem.